# Calculate Conditional Cumulative value based on specific logic

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, lubridate

I am new to R and have a data frame  called final as the main data set as shown below

```
dates_seq_ajay<-as.data.frame((seq(as.Date("2019/11/1"), by = "month", length.out = 6)))
ajay_emp_no <-1
ajay_ramped <-c(0,0,0,0,1,1)
ajay_loans <-c(1,22,17,25,21,23)
name<-"ajay"
data<-cbind(name,ajay_emp_no,dates_seq_ajay,ajay_ramped,ajay_loans)
colnames(data)<-c("name","emp_no","date","Flag","loans")


dates_seq_dv<-as.data.frame((seq(as.Date("2019/11/1"), by = "month", length.out = 4)))
dv_emp_no <-2
dv_flag <-c(0,0,0,0)
dv_loans <-c(2,15,42,1)
name<-"dv"
data1<-cbind(name,dv_emp_no,dates_seq_dv,dv_flag,dv_loans)
colnames(data1)<-c("name","emp_no","date","Flag","loans")



dates_seq_prince<-as.data.frame((seq(as.Date("2020/5/1"), by = "month", length.out = 5)))
prince_emp_no <-3
prince_flag <-c(0,0,0,1,1)
prince_loans <-c(16,31,28,32,23)
name<-"prince"
data2<-cbind(name,prince_emp_no,dates_seq_prince,prince_flag,prince_loans)
colnames(data2)<-c("name","emp_no","date","Flag","loans")

final<-rbind(data,data1,data2)
```

I have 1000's employee in my df and I want to find for each employee count of Month, performance and cumulative performance
such that if an employee has encountered flag 1 for first time then calculate for as desired in the o/p below above

if employee flag is 0 and does not have flag 1 then calculate Month, performance and cumulative performance till we have records for it.

For each employee

Month is the number of months he is present,

performance is the fraction of loan each month / total loans

total loan is sum of all loans till the flag is found for **1st time** , if flag is 0 always then total loans is sum of all loans

cumulative performance is taking cumulative sum of loan at each step for employee till we encouter flag 1

Output is shown below and is only for 3 employee but I need to have a common logic for all the 1000's employee

[image]

Comment: total loans, up to which row you are calculating

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're asking for, but it seems as though you want to use a conditional cumsum? You could look into creating a grouping based on run length encoding, for instance see the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581440/r-count-consecutive-occurrences-of-values-in-a-single-column-and-by-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We group by 'name', create a temporary column by taking the cumulative sum of 'Flag' ('tmp'), get the `row_number()` for 'Month', create the 'Performance', by dividing the 'loans' with `sum` of 'loans' based on the condition that 'tmp' is less than 2, and 'CumulativePerformance' by the cumulative sum of 'Performance'.  Then, we replace the row in these columns to NA based on the condition with 'tmp' column and remove the 'tmp'

```
library(dplyr) #1.0.0
final %>%
    group_by(name) %>% 
    mutate(tmp = cumsum(Flag), 
           Month = row_number(), 
           Performance= loans/sum(loans[tmp <2]), 
           CumulativePerformance = cumsum(Performance)) %>%
    mutate(across(Month:CumulativePerformance, ~ replace(., tmp > 1, NA))) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-tmp)
# A tibble: 15 x 8
#   name   emp_no date        Flag loans Month Performance CumulativePerformance
#   <chr>   <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <int>       <dbl>                 <dbl>
# 1 ajay        1 2019-11-01     0     1     1      0.0116                0.0116
# 2 ajay        1 2019-12-01     0    22     2      0.256                 0.267 
# 3 ajay        1 2020-01-01     0    17     3      0.198                 0.465 
# 4 ajay        1 2020-02-01     0    25     4      0.291                 0.756 
# 5 ajay        1 2020-03-01     1    21     5      0.244                 1     
# 6 ajay        1 2020-04-01     1    23    NA     NA                    NA     
# 7 dv          2 2019-11-01     0     2     1      0.0333                0.0333
# 8 dv          2 2019-12-01     0    15     2      0.25                  0.283 
# 9 dv          2 2020-01-01     0    42     3      0.7                   0.983 
#10 dv          2 2020-02-01     0     1     4      0.0167                1     
#11 prince      3 2020-05-01     0    16     1      0.150                 0.150 
#12 prince      3 2020-06-01     0    31     2      0.290                 0.439 
#13 prince      3 2020-07-01     0    28     3      0.262                 0.701 
#14 prince      3 2020-08-01     1    32     4      0.299                 1.00  
#15 prince      3 2020-09-01     1    23    NA     NA                    NA
```

---

If we have an earlier version of `dplyr`, use `mutate_at` instead of `mutate(across`

```
final %>%
        group_by(name) %>% 
        mutate(tmp = cumsum(Flag), 
               Month = row_number(), 
               Performance= loans/sum(loans[tmp <2]), 
               CumulativePerformance = cumsum(Performance)) %>%
        mutate_at(vars(Month:CumulativePerformance), ~ replace(., tmp > 1, NA)) %>%
        ungroup %>%
        select(-tmp)
```

Comment: we need to calculate till if flag is 1 and is encountered once "ONLY" and skip the rows onwards for the same employee

Comment: @Dexter what if there is no 1 in one of the groups

Comment: if you see the o/p 

ajay has 0 flag 4 times and 1 flag 2 time so we need to calculate for all 0 flag and 1st flag which is 1 so total 5 records for ajay 

dv has only 0 flag therfore calculate for all records

Comment: @Dexter one more doubt,  is it the same for the `sum(loans)`

Comment: if you see the o/p 

ajay has 0 flag 4 times and 1 flag 2 time so we need to calculate for all 0 flag and 1st flag which is 1 so total 5 records  calculation for ajay  in this case we need to sum for 5 loans

, Dv has only 0 flag therefore calculate for all records in this we need to sum for  loans

Comment: I am not able to run seems like across function is not available, are you using any specific package

Comment: @Dexter it is from `dplyr` 1.0.0.  Do you have a different version

Comment: Thanks @akrun, 
However when I try to execute the same for 1000 employee it is giving error
Error: Column `Performance` must be length 3 (the group size) or one, not 6

Comment: @Dexter Do you have any chance there are `NA` elements in `Flag` column?

Comment: @Dexter the `cumsum` returns `NA` if there is any NA value in that.  That is the reason I asked

Comment: no NA in the data, i check using sum(is.na(dataset))

Comment: @Dexter Is it possible to narrow down the group where it occurs and `dput` that sets of data so that it would be easier to check

Comment: @Dexter another case is that some groups have only 1s?

Comment: yes sum group has only 1 and no 0 flag, what should be done in that case

Comment: @Dexter can you please subset that group and update your post with the dput of that one.  Let me check it

Comment: I have dput the data for loans column we have null :(

Comment: @Dexter Please copy/paste the full output of the subset of data.  I cannot test on images

Comment: @Dexter By looking at the image, you have a `character` class column for 'loans',  I expected a `numeric` to get the `sum`.  Can you convert to numeric i.e. `final$loans <- as.numeric(final$loans)`