# Column that counts the reoccurring value in a column, reset at new value

Tags: r

I need to identify the instances for which a variable, `Var1`, in my dataframe takes on the *same value in a row* and, in particular, for how long the `Var1` takes on the same value in a row. I wish to add to the dataframe a new variable, `Var2`, which counts the total number that
 the repeated observation occur in a row. The dataframe is sorted by the `Date` variable. 
Let me illustrate: (`Var2` is the variable I wish to create)

```
     Date          Var1  Var2
#1   2020-01-01    0.9   1
#2   2020-01-02    0.2   2
#3   2020-01-03    0.2   2
#4   2020-01-04    0.8   1
#5   2020-01-05    0.3   3
#6   2020-01-06    0.3   3
#7   2020-01-07    0.3   3 
#8   2020-01-08    0.7   1
#9   2020-01-09    0.15  2
#10  2020-01-10    0.15  2
#11  2020-01-11    0.9   1
#12   2020-01-12   0.44  1
```

I hope my question formulation makes sense. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does your preferred output look like?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by 'output'. Could you please elaborate (I am fairly new to R). I want to create a numeric column to the dataframe. Thank you

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I see that `Var2` is actually your desired output. The answer below looks like it answers the question.

Comment: I think my question formulation might have been poor. I apologize. But I want `Var2` to 'reset' every time a new value in Var1 occurs. Say, `Var1=0.9` occurs again at `Date==2020-01-11`, I want `Var2=1`for `Date=2020-01-12` as it only occurs one time 'in-a-row' (I've edited my illustration above to include this). It seems like the answer Martin Gal have provided counts the number of times `Var1=0.9` in the entire column. Or is it just me applying it incorrectly to my original data set.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data.frame like this:

```r
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   Date        Var1
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01  0.9 
 2 2020-01-02  0.2 
 3 2020-01-03  0.2 
 4 2020-01-04  0.8 
 5 2020-01-05  0.3 
 6 2020-01-06  0.3 
 7 2020-01-07  0.3 
 8 2020-01-08  0.7 
 9 2020-01-09  0.15
10 2020-01-10  0.15
11 2020-01-11  0.9 
12 2020-01-12  0.44
```

using package `dplyr` and based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581440/r-count-consecutive-occurrences-of-values-in-a-single-column-and-by-group):

```
df %>%
  group_by(Var1, grp = with(rle(Var1), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
  mutate(Var2 = max(seq_along(grp))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)
```

gives you

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
   Date        Var1  Var2
   <date>     <dbl> <int>
 1 2020-01-01  0.9      1
 2 2020-01-02  0.2      2
 3 2020-01-03  0.2      2
 4 2020-01-04  0.8      1
 5 2020-01-05  0.3      3
 6 2020-01-06  0.3      3
 7 2020-01-07  0.3      3
 8 2020-01-08  0.7      1
 9 2020-01-09  0.15     2
10 2020-01-10  0.15     2
11 2020-01-11  0.9      1
12 2020-01-12  0.44     1
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer. However, I am not sure if I am applying the code incorrectly to my origianl data set or if I have been inaccurate in my question formulation, but I want `Var2` to 'reset' every time a new value in `Var1` occurs. Say, `Var1=0.9` occurs again at Date `2020-01-11`, I want Var2=1for Date `2020-01-12 as it only occurs one time 'in-a-row' (I've edited my illustration above to include this). It seems like this methodology counts the number of times `Var1=0.9` in the entire column. Or am I just applying your code incorrectly to my original data set.

Comment: Does `df %>%
  group_by(Date, Var1) %>%
  mutate(Var2 = n())` work?

Comment: No. But thank you  I think `df %>%   group_by(Date, Var1) %>%   mutate(Var2 = n())` 'resets' `Var2`
 at every new date (I only want `Var2` to 'reset' whenever Var1 takes on a new value)

Comment: @CecSK adjusted my answer.