# Finding scoring runs in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to find scoring runs using R. Say I have a tibble as below. I want to calculate the number of times one player scores five in a row (or any number) without the other player scoring. I thought about using `cumsum` but that doesn't really get me places. Ideally want to stick to `tidyverse` // using the pipe operator if possible. Thanks!

E.g.

```
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   player   runs
   <chr> <int>
 1 Bob       2
 2 Aaron     1
 3 Aaron     0
 4 Bob       4
 5 Aaron     1
 6 Aaron     0
 7 Bob       1
 8 Aaron     0
 9 Aaron     2
10 Bob       3
11 Bob       3
12 Aaron     2
```

Comment: Is this an arbitrary order or is the data already sorted?

Comment: @AndreWildberg the data is already sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dplyr 1.1.0 you can accomplish this with `consecutive_id()`. This is a simplification of @peter861222's answer.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~player, ~runs,
  "Bob",    2L,
  "Aaron",  1L,
  "Aaron",  0L,
  "Bob",    4L,
  "Aaron",  1L,
  "Aaron",  0L,
  "Bob",    1L,
  "Aaron",  0L,
  "Aaron",  2L,
  "Bob",    3L,
  "Bob",    3L,
  "Aaron",  2L
)

df %>%
  mutate(id = consecutive_id(player)) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(runs), .by = c(id, player))
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#>      id player total
#>   <int> <chr>  <int>
#> 1     1 Bob        2
#> 2     2 Aaron      1
#> 3     3 Bob        4
#> 4     4 Aaron      1
#> 5     5 Bob        1
#> 6     6 Aaron      2
#> 7     7 Bob        6
#> 8     8 Aaron      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Not dplyr, but it works:

```r
redfun <- function(prev, this) {
  dat <- quux[this,]
  if (dat$runs > 0) {
    prev[setdiff(names(prev), dat$player)] <- 0
    prev[dat$player] <- prev[dat$player] + dat$runs
  }
  prev
}
bind_rows(Reduce(redfun, seq_len(nrow(quux)), init = c(Bob=0, Aaron=0), accumulate = TRUE))[-1,] %>%
  bind_cols(quux, .)
#    player runs Bob Aaron
# 1     Bob    2   2     0
# 2   Aaron    1   0     1
# 3   Aaron    0   0     1
# 4     Bob    4   4     0
# 5   Aaron    1   0     1
# 6   Aaron    0   0     1
# 7     Bob    1   1     0
# 8   Aaron    0   1     0
# 9   Aaron    2   0     2
# 10    Bob    3   3     0
# 11    Bob    3   6     0
# 12  Aaron    2   0     2
```

From this you can see that `Bob` has one instance with cumulative unopposed runs exceeding 5.

Breakdown:

- `redfun` is a finite state machine of sorts: it is called once for each row in the frame (by `Reduce`) with `prev=` being the current state of all players (starting with `c(Bob=0, Aaron=0)`), and if the current row `runs` is greater than 0, it increments this player and resets the other player(s) to 0
- Typically `Reduce`'s function is meant to handle "data" (values), but in this case I'm iterating over the row numbers (1-12 in this case, by `seq_len(nrow(quux))`), and using that inside the inner function to index on the frame. In this way, every time `redfun` is called, `prev` (the first arg) is the state (starting at `0`/`0`), and `this` indicates the row of the frame to look at.
- Normally, `Reduce` just returns the last iteration of its cycles. We want all of the steps in between, so we set `accumulate=TRUE`.
- Because of how it is set up, `Reduce(.., accumulate=TRUE)` will return `nrow(quux) + 1` rows, where the first row is the initial state (of 0/0); we remove this with `[-1,]` after the call to reduce.
- The return from `Reduce` is a list with named values (each row's state), we can convert that easily into a frame with `dplyr::bind_rows`, and then we can directly combine it (column-wise) with the original frame using `dplyr::bind_cols`.

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(player = c("Bob", "Aaron", "Aaron", "Bob", "Aaron", "Aaron", "Bob", "Aaron", "Aaron", "Bob", "Bob", "Aaron"), runs = c(2L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

dplyr approach (credit to [Top answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581440/r-count-consecutive-occurrences-of-values-in-a-single-column-and-by-group))

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(player,grp = with(rle(player), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
  summarise(total_runs=sum(runs))%>%
  arrange(grp)

# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   player [2]
  player   grp total_runs
  <chr>  <int>      <int>
1 Bob        1          2
2 Aaron      2          1
3 Bob        3          4
4 Aaron      4          1
5 Bob        5          1
6 Aaron      6          2
7 Bob        7          6
8 Aaron      8          2
```